# es demux error: cannot peek when trying to make my computer speak with Python

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-speech-api, speech-synthesis, peek

I'm trying to get my computer to talk with google translate speech functionality on Ubuntu Utility Ubuntu16.04. I found a way to do it usning the voice library `speak` and [this repository](https://github.com/MauryaRitesh/Speech-to-Text-and-Text-to-Speech), but I have an error with VLC and I have not found a similar error on the Internet.

```
...
# for text to speech
import webbrowser as wb
import speak

# running music
from pygame import mixer
... 


class ActionTranslate(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_translate'

    def run (self,dispatcher,tracker,domain):

        try:
            # What Google thinks you said
            text = tracker.get_slot('sentenceToTranslate')
            if tracker.get_slot('voice') is 'en':
                lang = 'en' 
            else:
                lang = 'ko'

            # Google saying what he thinks you said
            speak.speak(text, lang)

            f_text = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + text
            wb.get(chrome_path).open(f_text)

        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

But I obtained this error:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): api.voicerss.org  
could not locate runnable browser

[00007ff164c0c2b8] es demux error: cannot peek
[00007ff164c0c2b8] es demux error: cannot peek
[mp3 @ 0x7ff164c5d860] Header missing
```

I know that peek refers to:

> a non-destructive operation performed on sequential,
>   collection-like data structures that have the notion of "top element"
>   or "next element", such as stacks, queues and streams. The `peek`
>   operation returns the value of the "top" (or "next") element without
>   "consuming" that element

Comment: It is better to use google official speech recognition/speech synthesis api instead. Or even dialogflow.